# Get specific Product for each category of a brand in WordPress Custom Post Types

Tags: php, mysql, magento, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type called `products` with its taxonomy called `category`

```
register_post_type( 'products',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Products' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Product' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Product' ),
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'Products'),
            'taxonomies'  => array( 'category' )
        )
    );
```

I have another which is `brands`

```
register_post_type( 'brands',
    // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Brands' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'BRAND' ), 
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Brand' ),
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'BRANDS'),
            'taxonomies'  => array( 'category' ),
        )
    );
```

I have a page called `page-brands.php` where i have used the below code to get all the brands.

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'brands', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$brands = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Then i am displaying brand title and logo..

```
<a class="hvr-grow" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
   <img src="<?php the_field('brand_logo'); ?>">
   <div class="brands_title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
</a>
```

It works perfectly, After clicking on the brand title which is a link. It goes to `single-brands.php` page. For Example, We have clicked on Brand title which is 'LG'. It will go to single-brands page and it will display all the products of its first category.

I'm getting its first category and saving it in `first_brand_category` by another function then using in below query to display.

```
$proucts_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 50,
    'post_type' => 'products',
    'cat' => $first_brand_category,
);
$products_query = new WP_Query($proucts_args);
```

Everything works until there perfectly. But now i want to change above query because i want to display one specific product for each category. For example..

Brand is `LG`
Categories for LG Brands are `TV` , `Mobiles` , `Air Conditioners` etc
There are multiple products for TV category & multiple products for mobiles etc.

I want to display one specific product of TV for LG, One specific product of Mobiles for LG and one specific product of Air Conditioners for LG with the hyper link of that category.

How can i do this? any suggestion, I am new to wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon your need.

If you know what specific product you need to display:
One way is to pass the product id in the parameters, Wp_query will return only that product. Please refer: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/. OR you can also sort the product and select only one product by giving 1 to post_count paramerter.

Comment: I have already read this, tried different solutions but nothing worked for me, not sure which one is correct also.

Comment: there will be many products. you should know which product need to get displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This Definitely help you to get the post of a specific category.

```
$args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'post type name',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'Post Taxonomy name',
                                'field'    => 'slug',
                                'terms'    => 'your slug' 

                          ),
                        ),
                    );
                    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

if you want to call your taxonomy by name then use this
'field'    => 'name',
'terms'    => 'your cat name'